# Powershell stripping the first character out of a variable when returning from function

Tags: powershell

I'm working on some PS code to automatically name a computer to our standards. There are two functions that build the name, one to grab the serial number and test if it is too long for the MS 15-character limit, the second puts the pieces together. When the get serial number function is called, everything works OK, but when the variable is read in the other function, it's missing the first character.

Here's the relevant code and log file:

```
Function Format-CompName {

    $compType = (Get-CimInstance Win32_SystemEnclosure).ChassisTypes
    WriteLog "Computer chassis type is: $compType"
    switch ($compType)
    {
        1{$WDWL = $desktop}
        2{$WDWL = $desktop}
        3{$WDWL = $desktop}
        4{$WDWL = $desktop}
        5{$WDWL = $desktop}
        6{$WDWL = $desktop}
        7{$WDWL = $desktop}
        8{$WDWL = $desktop}
        9{$WDWL = $laptop}
        10{$WDWL = $laptop}
        11{$WDWL = $laptop}
        12{$WDWL = $laptop}
        13{$WDWL = $laptop}
        14{$WDWL = $laptop}
        15{$WDWL = $laptop}
        16{$WDWL = $laptop}
        30{$WDWL = $laptop}
        31{$WDWL = $laptop}
        32{$WDWL = $laptop}
    }
 WriteLog "Prefix is: $prefix"
 WriteLog "Middle name is: $WDWL"
 Get-SerialNumber
 WriteLog "Post return SN..."
 WriteLog $strSN
 $strCompName = $prefix + $WDWL + $strSN
 WriteLog "Device name before Return: $strCompName"
 $strCompName
}  

Function Get-SerialNumber
{
# Get the serial number. Note: Lenovo now uses Win32_BIOS instead of Win32_Product (older machines may not work).
WriteLog "Getting the serial number."
$strSN = (Get-CimInstance Win32_BIOS).SerialNumber
WriteLog "Serial Number is:  $strSN"
#Is it too long?
if ($strSN.Length -gt 8) {
    WriteLog "Serial number is too long."
    $snNumDiff = $strSN.Length - 8
    #write-host $snNumDiff
    $strSN = $strSN.substring($snNumDiff) 
    return $strSN
    WriteLog "Adjusted SN is: " $strSN
}
else {
    WriteLog "Serial number is within character limits."
    WriteLog "Non-adjusted Serial number is: $strSN"
    return $strSN
}   
}
```

And the log...

```
2022/12/02 09:05:23 Naming script is starting
2022/12/02 09:05:23 Computer chassis type is: 10
2022/12/02 09:05:23 Prefix is: GU
2022/12/02 09:05:23 Middle name is: -WL-
2022/12/02 09:05:23 Getting the serial number.
2022/12/02 09:05:23 Serial Number is:  1RM4M13
2022/12/02 09:05:23 Serial number is within character limits.
2022/12/02 09:05:23 Non-adjusted Serial number is: 1RM4M13
2022/12/02 09:05:23 Post return SN...
2022/12/02 09:05:23 RM4M13
2022/12/02 09:05:23 Device name before Return: GU-WL-RM4M13
2022/12/02 09:05:23 Function returned: 
2022/12/02 09:05:23 New name =  1RM4M13 GU-WL-RM4M13
```

Logging all the details to isolate where the problem is.

Comment: You're not capturing the return value from `Get-SerialNumber`, so its unclear where the `$strSN` value comes from. (It's also not clear where `$desktop` and `$laptop` come from.)

Comment: To get serial number I would split on the colon and then trim.  Most likely the issue is there are tabs in the data (not spaces) so when you are subtracting 8 it is not correct.  You do not have space instead there are tabs.

Comment: Doesn't the "return $strSN" statement return that variable when it is called from Format-CompName? The return value is there, but missing it's first character.

Comment: `return "$strSN"` returns the _value_ of the _function-local` `$strSN` variable, it has no effect on the caller's variables. You need `$strSN = Get-SerialNumber` to capture the value on the caller's side.

Comment: The `Get-SerialNumber` callee function should be loaded before the `Format-CompName` caller function otherwise you invoke the `Get-SerialNumber` function from a higher scope (you might have pasted at the root/prompt). Long story short: What happens when you start a fresh PowerShell session?